# HTML to use for responsive design version of table data

Tags: html, css

I have a table of data which needs to display on a variety of devices down to 320px wide mobile phones

I'm planning on using css media queries to detect the browser windows size and show the responsive version once it gets below a certain level via { display: block; } and hide the standard version.

The responsive version will just stack the columns on top of each other.

My question is, what html tags should I use for the responsive version.  Currently I'm just using a bunch of divs which is functional but doesn't seem correct.  Or maybe it is?

```
<div class="standard_version">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Column A</th>
            <th>Column B</th>
            <th>Column C</th>
            <th>Column D</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>4rq4</td>
            <td>vdg34</td>
            <td>xcb245</td>
            <td>12341234</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>sdvxc4</td>
            <td>898fg</td>
            <td>sfasdf35</td>
            <td>451345</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>asdfasf</td>
            <td>zxdfw</td>
            <td>1A2313</td>
            <td>9732</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>


<div class="responsive_version">

    <div class="responsive_version_tr">
        <div class="responsive_version_th">Column A</div>
        <div class="responsive_version_th">Column B</div>
        <div class="responsive_version_th">Column C</div>
        <div class="responsive_version_th">Column D</div>
    </div>

    <div class="responsive_version_tr">
        <div class="responsive_version_td">4rq4</div>
        <div class="responsive_version_td">vdg34</div>
        <div class="responsive_version_td">xcb245</div>
        <div class="responsive_version_td">12341234</div>
    </div>

    <div class="responsive_version_tr">
        <div class="responsive_version_td">sdvxc4</div>
        <div class="responsive_version_td">898fg</div>
        <div class="responsive_version_td">sfasdf35</div>
        <div class="responsive_version_td">451345</div>
    </div>

    <div class="responsive_version_tr">
        <div class="responsive_version_td">asdfasf</div>
        <div class="responsive_version_td">zxdfw B</div>
        <div class="responsive_version_td">1A2313</div>
        <div class="responsive_version_td">9732</div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you (kindof) duplicate the DOM? And why do you add meaningless classes? Just style the table elements in the media queries as you would with that class of yours and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Divs will work just fine. However, have you looked into using pre-made html/css grid templates like [Skeleton](http://www.getskeleton.com/) or even complete frameworks like [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)? These are tried and true and are likely to be a fair bit more compatible than yours due to their large user base and support. See this stackexchange programmers post on ["reinventing the wheel"](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/29513/is-reinventing-the-wheel-really-all-that-bad)

Answer (score 0):

I would not use tables, because they are hard to rearrange responsively. I would use `<ul>` tags instead of `<tr>` and `<li>`'s instead of `<td>`. Also, if you want to go the quick route, just use [twitter-bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables) for your css base. And then have a separate stylesheet (included after bootstrap) to customize it. But even on the bootstrap tables, they just get a scroll-bar on mobile if the content is too big.

I would go with the tag substitution as i described, wrapped in a `div` with `display: table;` and give the `tr` `display: table-row;` and the `li` `display: table-cell;` And then change these styles in your mobile media queries. You can give the outer div a class of `table` if you are using bootstrap to make it look nice.